# Atom text editor is not determining (autocompleting) the folder path in HTML

Tags: html, autocomplete, atom-editor

My Atom text editor is not determining folders automatically. For example, if I want to put an image inside HTML, other text editors show me the path of folders automatically, but Atom doesn't. Is there any case? I am using Atom v1.47.0.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just worked after installation of the **autocomplete-paths** plugin by *atom-community*.